# Planar object Homography calculation and Pose Estimation

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography, pose-estimation

I'm trying to implement my own Homography and Pose estimation in OpenCV. Suppose I have a square image as a model which I want to locate in input frame from camera.
My question is about how to prepare model data to calculate Homography.

I did the following procedure:

1-I extracted 3 corresponding set in both images.

```
 Input features:       Model Features:
p1_Input(278,278)---> p1_model(137,273)
p2_Input(317,235)---> p2_model(176,230)
p3_Input(217,204)---> p3_model(76,199)  //all in pixel
```

2- Solving P3P problem:

a) normalizing input points using camera Intrinsic parameters:

```
u.x=(p1_Input.x - cx) / fx 
u.y=(p1_Input.y - cy) / fy  
u.z=1

v.x=(p2_Input.x - cx) / fx 
v.y=(p2_Input.y - cy) / fy  
v.z=1

w.x=(p3_Input.x - cx) / fx 
w.y=(p3_Input.y - cy) / fy  
w.z=1
```

b) normalizing the lenght in order to have a unit vector:

```
d = sqrt(u.x*u.x + u.y*u.y + 1);
u.x=u.x/d;
u.y=u.y/d;
u.z=u.z/d;  // and same for v and w
```

c)Finding distance between u and camera focus.(same for v and w) by solving p3p and storing in a,b and c

d)computing 3D coordinates:

```
A_Input.x=a*u.x;
A_Input.y=a*u.y;
A_Input.z=a*u.z;  // same for B_input and C_Input

like:
A_Input:(-0.0899342 ,0.0570672 ,0.976046)
B_Input:(-0.0197703 ,-0.0194311 ,0.955101) 
C_Input:(-0.197233 ,-0.0746457 ,0.967379)
```

3-Computing Homography

My question is arising here. How should I prepare and modify `p1_model,p2_model and p3_model` to be prepared for Homography computing?

Obviously  `A_Input` is 3D vector with normalized date while `p1_model` is 2D vector in pixel.

After solving the problem the rest would be as follows:

a)finding centeroid point for both set.

b)finding H using this formula dot prodoct

4- finding rigid transform using H and SVD

more detail is available [here](http://iplimage.com/blog/p3p-perspective-point-overview/#comment-60) and [here](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671)

Comment: you need 4 points to uniquely define a perspective transformation, are you making an affine approximation?

Comment: @Hammer No I used 3points to determine rigid transform rather perspective transform

Comment: I am still a bit confused, do you want a 2d rigid transform or a 3d one?  You can't get a 3d rigid transform unless you have 3d coordinates but it looks like you want to use the rigid transform to find your 3d coordinates (step c).  It seems a bit like pulling yourself up by your bootstraps.

Comment: I'm asking how to prepare 3D coordinate for calculation 6DOF rigid transform. As you can see I assume z=1 for the first set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as coordinate systems go, there is no specific "format" that you need to put your points in to get good results from a P3P (or [PnP](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-solvepnp)) algorithm, just be consistent.  The solution the algorithm is looking for given a correspondence between p1 and p2 is

```
p2 = [resulting_3x4_transform]*p1;
```

for each correspondence.  It may be advisable for numerical reasons to not have any coordinate values be very large or very small but other than that, feel free to put your points in any coordinate system you like.

Comment: You mean using a pixel format for one set and normalized one for another works?

Comment: no, I mean be consistent between sets.  You can use any Cartesian units you can imagine, just don't expect the transform you get back to work on anything other than the units you put in.

Comment: you could try posting a more specific question.  List the coordinates that go in, which function you are using, and the transform that comes out, along with why you think the transform is wrong.